# DllImport function pointer error

Tags: c#, callback, delegates, pinvoke, dllimport

I have C++ code like this:

```
typedef void (CALLBACK * VideoCaptureCB_Ptr)(PVOID pContext, BYTE * apData[3],
VideoSampleInfo_T * pVSI);

typedef struct _VideoSampleInfo_T
{
    ULONG   idFormat; // 
    ULONG   lSignalState;
    int     nLen; // not used for raw video data(e.g. YUV420)
    int     nWidth;
    int     nHeight;
    int     anPitchs[3]; // only used for raw video data(e.g. YUV420)
    ULONG   dwMicrosecsPerFrame; // 1000*1000/FPS
    ULONG   field;
    int     iSerial;

} VideoSampleInfo_T;

WD_RegisterVideoPreviewCB(HANDLE hChannel, PVOID pContext, VideoCaptureCB_Ptr pCB);
```

And i write C# code to use WD_RegisterVideoPreviewCB() in C#

```
public delegate void VideoCaptureCB_Ptr(IntPtr pContext, byte[] apData, VideoSampleInfo_T pVSI);
 public static void HandleVideoStatic(IntPtr pContext, byte[] apData, VideoSampleInfo_T pVSI)
        {

        }
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct VideoSampleInfo_T
    {

        public uint idFormat;
        public uint lSignalState;
        public int nLen; // not used for raw video data(e.g. YUV420)
        public int nWidth;
        public int nHeight;
        public int[] anPitchs ; // only used for raw video data(e.g. YUV420)
        public uint dwMicrosecsPerFrame; // 1000*1000/FPS
        public uint field;
        public int iSerial;

    }
WD_RegisterVideoPreviewCB(m_ahChannels[i],   m_aMediaHandler[i], HandleVideoStatic);
```

Before Irun my C# code I put one debbugging poin at HandleVideoStatic(). When i run my code. the VS 2013 is not stop at the debugging point :(

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your translations. First the struct. The inline array is declared incorrectly. You need it like this:

```
public struct VideoSampleInfo_T
{
    public uint idFormat;
    public uint lSignalState;
    public int nLen; 
    public int nWidth;
    public int nHeight;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=3)]
    public int[] anPitchs;
    public uint dwMicrosecsPerFrame;
    public uint field;
    public int iSerial;
}
```

Next the delegate. The array parameter is an array of pointers to byte. It is not a byte array. And the struct must be passed by ref. Perhaps declare it like this.

```
public delegate void VideoCaptureCB_Ptr(
    IntPtr pContext, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst=3)]
    IntPtr[] apData, 
    ref VideoSampleInfo_T pVSI
);
```